# Create multi-level structure for firebase

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

I am newbie to angularjs and firebase.
I want to create a small web app for searching books. I am getting stuck at structuring database. 
My database is 3 levels: Category -> Topics -> Books. For each book, I save 2 values for Book Store and Book Content.
I am trying to use flatten-type of json as below:

```
    {
        "book":{
            "category":{
                "finance":{
                    "catId": 1,
                    "catName": "Finance"
                },
                "education":{
                    "catId": 2,
                    "catName": "Education"
                }
            },
            "topic": {
                "finance":{
                    "topicName": "Earn some money",
                    "topicName": "Buy some thing"
                },
                "education":{
                    "topicName": "Learn some thing",
                    "topicName": "Take some class"
                }
            },
            "book":{
                "finance":{
                    "book1": {
                        "bookName": "A millionaire",
                        "bookContent": "This book very good"
                    },
                    "book2":{
                        "bookName": "New book",
                        "bookContent": "Content of book"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get all books belonging to a topic, but I don't know who to structure database for it to use ng-repeat in AngularJS. 
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I got familiar with 2 levels database, but more than 3 levels are very new to me.

Comment: Did you read https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html, specifically the section about flattening your data? Aside from that: it'll be easier to help you if you share some of the Angular code you already wrote.